# Two tiny puzzles of pattern or reformat

Tags: pattern-matching

Q1:

(This question was adapted from the last example of [Naming Pieces of Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NamingPiecesOfPatterns) in Wolfram Documentation.)

Modify the pattern (but requiring retain `h[_]`) —

```
{f[h[4],h[4]],  f[h[4],h[5]],  f[h[4],h[5],h[6]]} /. f[x:h[_], x_] -> r[x]
```

— to output

```
{f[h[4],h[4]],  r[h[5]],  r[h[6]]}
```

---

Q2:

Use **as little code as possible** to generate:

```
{{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}, {{{9, 10}, {11, 12}}, {{13, 14}, {15, 16}}}}
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 9 & 10 \\
 11 & 12 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 13 & 14 \\
 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

My trial:

```
m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
{{m, m + 4}, {m + 8, m + 12}}
```

Comment: As part of the Mathematica community that you are now, you should probably re-read some of the topics in the [help-center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). It is good practice to not only accept answers but to upvote all helpful answers. Coolwaters replacement approach for instance is worth an upvote. Just saying..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you try to achieve in your first example. Nevertheless, here is a more verbose version of what coolwater used:

```
{f[h[4], h[4]], f[h[4], h[5]], f[h[4], h[5], h[6]]} /. 
  {f[x_, x_] :> f[x, x], f[start__, last_] :> r[last]}
```

Your second question has several answers. You can construct the matrix or you can restructure an existing list:

```
Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, Range[16], 3]
(i = 1; Nest[{#, # + (i *= 2)} &, {1, 2}, 3])
First@Nest[{{First[#], First[#] + Last[#]}, Last[#]*2} &, {{1, 2}, 2}, 3]
(i = 1; Table[i++, 2, 2, 2, 2])
SparseArray[{i_, j_, k_, l_} :> 8 (i - 1) + 4 (j - 1) + 2 (k - 1) + l, {2, 2, 2, 2}] // Normal
Internal`Deflatten[Range[16], {2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

Comment: I have to apologize that Q1 has been modified to my original meaning, can you relook it?

Comment: What do you mean by "retain `h`"? Do you mean that you need to ensure that the functions inside `f` are `h[..]`?

Comment: Yes. *Supposing* that I require `h[..]` to be included in `f`.

Comment: @ooo You can use `{f[x_h, x_h] :> f[x, x], f[start__h, last_h] :> r[last]}`. Works the same but enforces the that the subexpressions have a head `h`.

Answer (score 9):

E.g.

```
Replace[{f[h[4], h[4]], f[h[4], h[5]], f[h[4], h[5], h[6]]},
   {a_[b__] :> If[DuplicateFreeQ[List[b]], r[Last[{b}]], a[b]]}, {1}]
(*or*)
{f[h[4], h[4]], f[h[4], h[5]], f[h[4], h[5], h[6]]} /.
    f[x : h[_], y__] /; x =!= First[{y}] :> r[Last[{y}]]
```

> ```
> {f[h[4], h[4]], r[h[5]], r[h[6]]}
> ```

```
ArrayReshape[Range[16], ConstantArray[2, 4]] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 2 \\
>  3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  5 & 6 \\
>  7 & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  9 & 10 \\
>  11 & 12 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  13 & 14 \\
>  15 & 16 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: I have to apologize that Q1 has been modified to my original meaning, can you relook it?

Comment: @ooo Edited the answer

Comment: Wouldn't `{2,2,2,2}` be shorter than `ConstantArray[2, 4]`? It depends on what "as little code as possible" means but I understand it as golfing.

Comment: @anderstood `ConstantArray[2, 4]` is better than I desired~

Answer (score 2):

#### Q1

```
{f[h[4], h[4]], f[h[4], h[5]], f[h[4], h[5], h[6]]} /. 
   f[x_, y___, z_] /; FreeQ[{y, z}, x] :> r[z]
```

> {f[h[4], h[4]], r[h[5]], r[h[6]]}

#### Q2

```
i=1;Table[i++,2,2,2,2]
```

> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}, {{{9, 10}, {11, 12}}, {{13, 
>       14}, {15, 16}}}}

```
%  // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 2 \\
>  3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  5 & 6 \\
>  7 & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  9 & 10 \\
>  11 & 12 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  13 & 14 \\
>  15 & 16 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively,  with three extra characters:

```
i=1;Array[i++&,{2,2,2,2}]
```